# QGIS 2.14 map rendering issue when symbolising on attributes from a join

Tags: qgis

I have a spatial table that has a join to non-spatial table. I then symbolise using the joined attribute from the non-spatial table.

If the join is non cached, the rendering on QGIS freezes. I am using a PostGIS view for the non-spatial table, but I got the same results using a CSV joined the same way.

However if I cache the join the map will render; however there is no way to refresh the join, except going into the layer properties and doing a 'fake edit' on the join.

Is this a bug or are there any particular settings/limitations on joining spatial/non-spatial tables in QGIS 2.14?

Note: I didn't have this rendering issue in 2.12 or 2.8